# How to update variable in IO/access variable made in if statement in haskell

Tags: variables, haskell, if-statement

I have some code where I create an object at the beginning. Then I want to run various updates on the object depending on different commands.

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Enter command, c x y, d x y"
    s <- getLine
    let object = newObject
    if head s == 'c' then
        let object2 = updateObject object s in
        print object
    else if head s == 'd' then
        let object2 = updateObject object s in
        print object
    else do
        print "Error, try again"
        main
    putStrLn "Enter new command"
    c <- getLine
    print $ updateObject object2 c
```

Error:

```
Variable not in scope: object2 :: Object
```

How do I make the object "global" for the main function so that changes done to the object inside the if statements can be used later?

How can I do this in a better way?

Comment: just create a function that returns object2. Why are you if-and-els'ing anyway, both paths execute the same code

Comment: Thanks! They are supposed to different things when the code is done.
What do you mean by making a function that returns object 2? The function updateObject returns object2, but I run it at different times with different parameters. I'm going to have several different if's with different updates. How can I then access the final object with all the updates?

Comment: `let object2 = updateObject object s in` defines `object2` for expression after `in`. You are trying to use it outside. Hense compiler errors.

Comment: `let object = newObject` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @chepner The idea was to create an initial object that I could run updates on, since updateObject requires an object to begin with.

Comment: That's not what it does. It just makes `object` another name for whatever `newObject` is. This leads me to ask, what is the type of `newObject`? If it's a function, you are never calling it (unless that's part of what `updateObject` does).

Comment: @SebastianPaulsen don't forget to close the question by selecting a solution or by deleting your post. People will waste time trying to help you while you're not in need of it anymore.

Comment: oh sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow. Done what you said!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to do too much in main, if and else logic shouldn't exist there. Move all that stuff to a different function and keep main clean and easy.
The if and else logic I use here is valid because it is directly related to the flow of the appliation, rather than a domain choice (i.e. domain = should I update via this function or this function vs application = is this input I got valid for my program, should I terminate or not).

Try this:

```
    main = do
        putStrLn "Enter command, c x y, d x y"
        s <- getLine
        if not $ validateInput s then
             print "Error, try again"
             main
        else do
            let object = newObject
            updateObject object s
            print object  


updateObject :: a -> String -> a
updateObject object s
          | head s == 'c' = --do updates here
          | head s == 's' = --do updates here
```

Also try to create a console loop so you can easier deal with "Enter new Command" situations. Move away from main as soon as you can.

Comment: Using `head` here is poor practice; what if `s` is an empty string?

Comment: @Glubus Thanks! I think I've got an idea on how to fix it based on what you're writing here.

Comment: @chepner what if s doesn't start with either 's' or 'c'? This is just an example that emphasizes separation of concerns. updateObject is not a robust function at all That said, validateInput at line 4 should imply the stability of this program (not that that is an excuse not to write crashable code elsewhere).

Comment: The original code handled inputs other than `s` and `c`; you've taken a step *backward* in that regard.

Comment: @chepner Yes, this is the point I was after posing that question to you. My answer is not illustrating how one should validate input, hence "what if s is an empty string" is an irrelevant question. I've added this non-implemented function `ValidateInput` to show that this snippet expects some logic in that regard. My answer talks about how to structure code, so that OP can solve his problem while maintaining proper style. I left out validation on purpose because it's trivial anyway and only clutters code that does matter.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that: functions like `Object -> Object`, monad `State`, `IORef` and etc. The way depends on what do you want to do exactly.

The most simplest way (for beginner) is to do that by the function, which generate updated version of your object.

For example:

```
updateObject :: Command -> Object -> Maybe Object
updateObject command initialObject = case command of
    'c':_ -> Just $ ... -- update initialObject by the 'c' command
    'd':_ -> Just $ ... -- update initialObject by the 'd' command
    _     -> Nothing    -- invalid command

main = do
    putStrLn "Enter command, c x y, d x y"
    command <- getLine
    case updateObject command newObject of
        Just updatedObject -> print updatedObject
        Nothing -> do
            print "Error, try again"
            main
```